# Ancient greeks know about leap day?

Tags: the-sun, the-moon, moon-phases

I'm reading about Antikythera machine and its functions.
So I read about solar cycle and moon cycle and how they used 19 solar years to compare with 235 lunar cycles.

So this is my question: They know about leap day at the time (~ 200 BC)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This might be better suited to HSM.SE  (history of science)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If a question is ontopic on multiple sites, the relevant SE ruling is that it remains where it is opened.

Comment: This is more about ancient calendar trivia than it is about the history of astronomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, they know according to the Metonic Calendar created in ~430 B.C.

To know more about [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle).